# Creating global php variable to manage request rates

Tags: wordpress, request, endpoint

I'm using a webhook in a wordpress project, every time webhook is triggered by another system my wordpress endpoint recieves a POST data and send to the server (the server which webhook is being triggered) a GET request,the problem is when webhooks are too much to the point I make many GET requests and got ip blocked for 10min, I created a php global variable which is 1 if a request will be made in the next line of code and 0 otherwise, if this global variable already exists and it's 1, so my code will wait few miliseconds to make a new request so normalizing my request rate. But I really need a consistent method to deal with that problem, I don't know if any instability in my server can bug this php variable to the point it becomes useless, what are the possibles issues regarding this approach?

I was thinking create a rule with wait the next request if current request rate is near to my limit rate, but I think it'd be the same.